# Hibernate add sequence based on date

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, hibernate3

I have this table on Sql Server

- id int
- journal_date datetime
- sequence int

What im trying to do is generate a sequence based on the datetime value.

example of the database

```
| id | journal_date | sequence |
--------------------------------
|  1 | 2012-01-01   |      1   |
|  2 | 2012-01-01   |      2   |
|  3 | 2012-01-02   |      1   |
|  4 | 2012-01-01   |      3   |
```

How to do this on hibernate model and the annotations ?

Comment: I don't know how to do this in hibernate. But in general, you can try this. `select max(sequence)+1 from table where journal_date = input_date`

Comment: And? What problem do you have? What have you tried? WHat's your question?

Comment: Im sorry i was in a hurry, how to do this automatically in hibernate ? I use hibernate with annotation in model.

Comment: There is no way to do this "automatically' in Hibernate. You'll have to implement something yourself, with Hibernate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to fill up the sequence column the first time

```
UPDATE journaltable t1 SET sequence =
  (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM journaltable t2
   WHERE t2.journal_date = t1.journal_date AND t2.id < t1.id);
```

and to keep it in sync either use a trigger with

```
UPDATE journaltable t1 SET sequence =
  (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM journaltable t2 WHERE t2.journal_date = t1.journal_date AND t2.id < t1.id)
  WHERE t1.id = @newlyInsertedId;
```

or handle it in Code using Hibernate